# implementing parser - using recursive decsent

Tags: c, parsing

I have been trying to develop a program which implements a parser, i.e., syntactic analysis.

Here is what I have done so far:

**parser.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.h"

void error_handle(char *expected, YYSTYPE *token) {
    if (token) {
        fprintf(yyout, "Error: Expected token is { %s }, but actual token is [ %s ] at line %d\n", expected, token->lexeme, token->line);
        recovery = 1;
    }
}

void print_token(char *str, YYSTYPE *token) {
    if (token) 
        fprintf(yyout, str, token->lexeme, token->line);
}



int parser() {
    parser_errors = 0;
    recovery = 0;
    token = tokens;

    if (!token)
        return 0;

    fprintf(yyout, "Starting Program...\n");

    if (!match(PROGRAM)) {
        error_handle("program", token);
        recovery = 0;
    }
    else
        print_token("[ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

    next_token();

    var_definitions();

    statements();

    if (!match(END)) {
        error_handle("end", token);
        recovery = 0;
    }
    else
        print_token("[ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

    next_token();

    func_definitions();

    return parser_errors;
}


void var_definitions() {
    if (!type()) 
        if (not_var_definitions()) 
            return;

    fprintf(yyout, "Variable Definitions...\n");

    while (token) {
        if (!type()) {
            if (not_var_definitions()) {
                recovery = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        var_definition();
        if (match(')'))
            break;
        if (!match(SEMICOLON))
            error_handle(";", token);
        next_token();
    }
}

void var_definition() {
    if (type()) 
        print_token("Variable Type [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
    else if (!type()) 
        error_handle("integer, real", token);
    next_token();
    variables_list();
}

void variables_list() {
    int error;
    do {
        error = not_var_definitions();
        variable();
        if (error == 2) {
            error_handle(",", token);
            while (!match(COMMA) && !match(SEMICOLON))
                next_token();
            recovery = 0;
        }
    } while (match(COMMA) && next_token());
}

void variable() {
    token->lexeme[token->count] = '\0';
    if (!match(ID)) {
        if (recovery) {
            while (!match(ID) && !match(COMMA) && !match(SEMICOLON)) 
                next_token();
            recovery = 0;
            if (!match(ID)) return;
        }
        else error_handle("Variable Name(id)", token);
    }
    next_token();
    if (match('[')) {
        if (!recovery) {
            back_token();
            if (token) 
                fprintf(yyout, "Array Variable %s\n", token->lexeme);
            next_token();
        }
        next_token();
        if (!match(INT_NUMBER)) {
            error_handle("int number", token);
        }
        else 
            print_token("Array Size [%s] at line %d\n", token);
        next_token();
        if (!match(']') && token) {
            if (recovery) {
                while (!match(']'))
                    next_token();
                recovery = 0;
            }
            else 
                error_handle("]", token);
        }
        next_token();
    }
    else {
        if (!recovery) {
            back_token();
            print_token("Variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
            next_token();
        }
    }
}

void statements() {
    if (not_statements()) 
        return;

    fprintf(yyout, "Statement List...\n");

    while (!not_statements()) {
        statement();
        if (!match(SEMICOLON)) {
            if (recovery) {
                while (!match(SEMICOLON) && !match('{') && !match(END))
                    if (!next_token()) 
                        break;
                recovery = 0;
            }
            else 
                error_handle(";", token);
        }
        if (match(END)) 
            break;
        if (match('{')) 
            continue;
        next_token();
        if (match(SEMICOLON)) 
            next_token();
    }
}

void statement() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Statement...\n");

    if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        if (match('(')) {
            back_token();
            function_call();
        }
        else {
            back_token();
            fprintf(yyout, "Variable Assignment...\n");

            variable();

      if (!match('=')) {
        if (!match(SEMICOLON)) 
            error_handle("=", token);
        if (recovery) {
            while (!match('=') && !match(SEMICOLON) && !match('{') && !match(END)) 
                next_token();
                recovery = 0;
            if (match(SEMICOLON) || match('{') || match(END)) 
                return;
            print_token("Assign Operator [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
        }
     } 
     else 
        print_token("Assign Operator [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

            next_token();
            if (!expression()) {
                if (match(END) || match('{')) 
                    return;
                error_handle("int number, real number, id", token);
                next_token();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (match(RETURN)) {
        fprintf(yyout, "Return Statement...\n");
        next_token();
        if (match(SEMICOLON)) 
            fprintf(yyout, "Empty Statement\n");
        else {
            if (!expression()) 
                error_handle("ID, int number, real number", token);
            expression();
        }
    }
    else if (match('{')) 
        block();
}

void function_call() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Function Call...\n");
    print_token("Function Name [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

    next_token(); 
    next_token();
    parameters_list();

    if (!match(')')) {
        error_handle(", or )", token);
        next_token();
        while (!match(')') && !match(SEMICOLON)) 
            next_token();
        back_token();
    }
    next_token();
}

void parameters_list() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Parameters List...\n");

    if (match(')')) {
        fprintf(yyout, "Empty Parameter\n");
    }
    else 
        variables_list();
}

int expression() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Expression...\n");

    if (recovery) {
        while (!match(INT_NUMBER) && !match(REAL_NUMBER) && !match(ID) && !match('{')) 
            next_token();
        recovery = 0;
        if (match('{')) 
            return 0;
    }

    if (match(INT_NUMBER)) {
        print_token("int number [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
        next_token();
    }
    else if (match(REAL_NUMBER)) {
        print_token("real number [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
        next_token();
    }
    else if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        if (ar_op()) {
            back_token();
            print_token("ID [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
            next_token();
            print_token("Arithmetic Operator [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
            next_token();
            if (!expression()) {
                error_handle("int number, real number, id", token);
                next_token();
            }
        }
        else {
            back_token();
            variable();
        }
    }
    else 
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

void block() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Block Statement...\n");

    if (!match('{')) {
        if (match(END)) 
            return;
        error_handle("{", token);
    }
    next_token();

    var_definitions();

    back_token();
    if (!match(SEMICOLON) && !match('{')) {
        if (match(END)) 
            return;
        error_handle(";", token);
    }

    next_token();

    statements();

    if (!match('}')) {
        if (match(END)) 
            return;
        error_handle("}", token);
    }

    next_token();
}

void func_definitions() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Function Definitions List...\n");

    while (token) 
        func_definition();
}

void func_definition() {
    if (!returned_type()) {
        error_handle("integer, real, void", token);
        while (!returned_type() && !match(ID)) 
            next_token();
    }

    recovery = 0;

    fprintf(yyout, "Function Definition...\n");
    if (returned_type()) 
        print_token("Return Type [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
    else 
        error_handle("integer, real, void", token);
    next_token();

    if (!match(ID)) 
        error_handle("id", token);
    else 
        print_token("Function Name [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
    next_token();

    if (!match('(')) 
        error_handle("(", token);
    next_token();

    param_definitions();

    if (!match(')')) 
        error_handle(")", token);
    next_token();

    block();
    if (recovery) {
        while (!match('}')) next_token();
        next_token();
        recovery = 0;
    }
}

void param_definitions() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Parameter definitions List...\n");
    if (match(')')) 
        fprintf(yyout, "Empty Parameter\n");
    else 
        var_definitions();

}
```

**parser.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "LEXYY.h"

int recovery, parser_errors;
FILE *yyout;

void error_handle(char *, YYSTYPE *);
void print_token(char *, YYSTYPE *);

int parser();
void var_definitions();
void var_definition();
void variables_list();
void variable();
void statements();
void statement();
void function_call();
void parameters_list();
int expression();
void block();
void func_definitions();
void func_definition();
void param_definitions();
```

**LEXYY.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct YYTYPE {
    int kind;
    char *lexeme;
    int line;
    int count;
    struct YYTYPE *next;
    struct YYTYPE *prev;
} YYSTYPE;

YYSTYPE *token;
YYSTYPE *tokens;
int line_number;
int lexer_errors;

void initLexer();
void create_and_store_token(int, char *, int);

#define PROGRAM 256
#define END 257
#define INTEGER 258
#define REAL 259
#define INT_NUMBER 260
#define REAL_NUMBER 261
#define ID 262
#define VOID 263
#define RETURN 264
#define COMMA 265
#define SEMICOLON 266

YYSTYPE *next_token();
YYSTYPE *back_token();
int match(int);

int type();
int ar_op();
int returned_type();
int not_var_definitions();
int not_statements();
```

**LEXYY.c**

```
%option nounistd
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include "LEXYY.h"
#define isatty _isatty
#define fileno _fileno
void initLexer();
void create_and_store_token(int, char *, int);
void errorPrint(char);
void illegalError(const char *, const char *);
%}

WHITESPACE          ([ \t]+)
NEWLINE             (\r|\n|\r\n)
COMMENT             ("--"[^\r\n]*)
ID                  ([A-Za-z]([_]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)
ILLEGALID           ([_][A-Za-z0-9_]*|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*[_]|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z]([_]*[A-Za-z0-9]*)*)
INTEGER             (0|[0-9]+)
REAL                (0\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
WRONGNUMBER         ([0][0-9]+|[0][0-9]+[.][0-9]*|[.][0-9]+|[0-9]+[.])
OPERATOR            ([*/=])
SEPARATION          ([[\]{}\(\)])

%%

{NEWLINE}           { line_number++; }
{WHITESPACE}+       {}
{COMMENT}           {}

"program"           { return PROGRAM; }
"end"               { return END; }
"real"              { return REAL; }
"integer"           { return INTEGER; }
"void"              { return VOID; }
"return"            { return RETURN; }
{INTEGER}           { return INT_NUMBER; }
{REAL}              { return REAL_NUMBER; }
{WRONGNUMBER}       { illegalError(yytext, "Number"); }
","                 { return COMMA; }
";"                 { return SEMICOLON; }

{ID}                { return ID; }
{ILLEGALID}         { illegalError(yytext, "ID"); }

{OPERATOR}          { return yytext[0]; }
{SEPARATION}        { return yytext[0]; }

.                   { errorPrint(yytext[0]); }

%%

void initLexer() {
    line_number = 1;
    lexer_errors = 0;
    tokens = NULL;
    token = NULL;
}

void create_and_store_token(int kind, char *lexeme, int line) {
    if (token == NULL) {
        tokens = (YYSTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(YYSTYPE));
        token = tokens;
        token->next = NULL;
        token->prev = NULL;
    } else {
        token->next = (YYSTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(YYSTYPE));
        token->next->next = NULL;
        token->next->prev = token;
        token = token->next;
    }
    token->kind = kind;
    token->line = line;
    token->lexeme = (char *)malloc(sizeof(lexeme) + 1);
#ifdef _WIN32
    strcpy_s(token->lexeme, strlen(lexeme) + 1, lexeme);
#else
    strcpy(token->lexeme, lexeme);
#endif
}

YYSTYPE *next_token() {
    if (token) 
        return (token = token->next);
    return NULL;
}

YYSTYPE *back_token() {
    if (token) 
        return (token = token->prev);
    return NULL;
}

int match(int kind) {
    if (token && token->kind == kind) 
        return kind;
    return 0;
}

int type() {
    return (match(REAL) ? REAL : match(INTEGER));
}

int ar_op() {
    if (match('*') || match('/')) 
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int returned_type() {
    return (match(VOID) ? VOID : type());
}

int not_var_definitions() {
    int flag = 0;
    if (!token) 
        flag = 1;
    else if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        if (match('=') || match('('))
            flag = 2;

        if (match('[')) {
            next_token();
            next_token();
            next_token();
            if (match('=') || match('('))
                flag = 2;

            back_token();
            back_token();
            back_token();
        }
        back_token();
    }

    else 
        flag = 3;
    return flag;

}

int not_statements() {
    if (!token) 
        return 1;
    if (!match(ID) && !match(RETURN) && !match('{')) 
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void errorPrint(char ch) {
    fprintf(yyout, "The character '%c' at line: %d does not begin any legal token in the language.\n", ch, line_number);
}

void illegalError(const char *text, const char *type) {
    fprintf(yyout, "Illegal %s '%s' was found at line %d\n", type, text, line_number);
}
```

**However, I guess it's a rather cumbersome way to implement the parser.
How would edit my code, for using the technique of "recursive descent"?**

I know that in order to get it being used you need to perform a left recursion on the grammar, and the left common element is called. However, I find it difficult to apply it.

Comment: Do you have a specific answerable question? If your code works and you are looking for a review then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be what you are looking for.

Comment: You're already using recursive descent, although there isn't any recursion yet. But you're writing much more code than necessary.

Comment: @user207421 how would you make it more simple?